# Zimbra Restoring mailboxes get 403 upload file too long

Tags: migration, zimbra, mailbox

I have Zimbra 8.0 i'm migrating account from other server but the account the .tgz files have between 800MB and 3.8GB i haveing problems. I've change

```
zimbraMtaMaxMessageSize 
zimbraFileUploadMaxSize
```

to 4GB but always i get the same error.

**Note**: after any change in the config always restart with `zmcontrol restart`

Answer (score 0):

Try this command

```
/opt/zimbra/bin/zmmailbox -z -m user@domain.com postRestURL “//?fmt=tgz&resolve=reset” /tmp/account.tgz
```

Or, if you are still having problems, you can use CURL method

```
curl -k -u admin:PASSWORD --data-binary @/path/to/USER-account.tgz "https://MAILSTORE-FQDN:7071/service/home/USER@DOMAIN/?fmt=tgz&resolve=skip"
```